# Can I change the locale on a Windows Azure Website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, localization

We have a range of Classic ASP applications that we are looking to port to the new Windows Azure Website hosting.

The Classic ASP websites are written against a server that was running in UK locale. The classic ASP has been coded to use UK datetime formats in various ways in hundreds of pages. When I have previously tried the code on servers with US locale the datetime handling fails as the datetime format is different.

Does anyone know if I can specifiy the locale for the website?

Alternatively does anyone know how to change the locale on a standard web role with a start-up task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to configure the website globalization, it is best to perform using [globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0%28VS.71%29.aspx) element.

To change locale of your website you can set the **culture and uiculture** properly in  web.config.

In Windows Azure if you want to do it in startup task you would need to create a batch file (**i.e. global.cmd**) in which can run the following command:

```
Appcmd set config /commit:WEBROOT /section:globalization /culture: string
Appcmd set config /commit:WEBROOT /section:globalization /uiCulture: string
```

Above change the "string" to your desired locale code.

Finally you can create startup task as defined in the ServiceDefinition.csdef

```
<Startup>
 <Task commandLine="global.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" />
</Startup>
```

Comment: this would work for a Web Role in Cloud Services, not for Windows Azure Web Sites where you cannot set startup tasks.

Comment: FYI this was working for me on 2008 based VMs but recently started using a 2012 VM and the two AppCmd's give an error now.

Comment: Solved 2012 VM image issue.  You need to remove space between /culture: string, eg. /culture:eb-GB = works